# Showing Joomla menu on external page

Tags: php, joomla, module

Hi I am trying to show joomla menu on my external page here is my code on external php file , is there any other way to do the same , thanks in advance for help.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/../' );   // should point to joomla root

define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

$mainframe->initialise();


jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );

$module = JModuleHelper::getModules('xxxx');

echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module[0]);
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, what do you mean by _external page_

Comment: i want to use it on php page

Comment: With the code you're currently using, are you receiving any errors? If not, what's currently happening? You may also want to consider asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You can't just start an html page with nothing. Look at some of the examples of stand alone web applications. also are you sure `$module` has data? I agree with @Lodder's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples of how to do this are shown in the offline.php and error.php templates.

e.g.

```
$app             = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc             = JFactory::getDocument();
//all the code to start your html
        <div class="navigation">
            <?php // Display position-1 modules ?>
            <?php echo $doc->getBuffer('modules', 'position-1', array('style' => 'none')); ?>
        </div>

// all the code to end your html
```

That is from protostar.